# How to add or get the {github.sha} to cucumber url in ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber, github-actions, gherkin, site-prism

I have the following code:

```
def index_page

visit 'https://www.company.com/?&ui_version=912c739e8450c9fc0705eeae12715656716f42c3'

end
```

I need to replace the rest of the path with the {github.sha} that generates github actions in my project where I use cucumber, ruby and site prism.

Example:

```
def index_page

visit 'https://www.company.com/{github.sha}'

end
```

Comment: Is the below query in the URL a constant one ? `?&ui_version=912c739e8450c9fc0705eeae12715656716f42c3`

Answer (score 0):

Below should work

```
- name: Replace with GitHub sha
  env:
    GITHUB_SHA: ${{github.sha}}
  run: |
   sed -e 's|https://www.company.com/?&ui_version=912c739e8450c9fc0705eeae12715656716f42c3|https://www.company.com/$GITHUB_SHA|g' index.html
```